# Problem installing .sh file

Tags: bash, sh

I have this file `Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh` that I need to install in my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I have already, successfully, run `chmod +x Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`. However, when I run `sudo ./Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`, I get the error:

`./Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh: 1: ./Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh: Syntax error: ")" unexpected`

I have already tried `sudo sh Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`, but I get the same error. I also tried `sudo bash Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`, and I get:

`Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh: Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh: cannot execute binary file`

What shall I do?

Thanks very much in advance.

**EDIT:**

`file Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh` returns `Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh: data`

`head Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh` is taking too long to return anything (the file has 2.7 GB, maybe that's why...)

**EDIT 2:**

`md5sum Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh` returns `7d485364cbd273fee95cdb8cc523b143  Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`

I got the file from a friend, not sure the original source. I know, however, that it worked in his machine. Maybe it got corrupted during the transfer or something...

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of `head Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh` and `file Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already edited the post with the `file` information. The `head` information is taking too long, I'll post it when it returns anything.

Comment: Despite the name, that is not a shell script. It is also not an executable file. My guess is that it got corrupted.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us where you got the file, how we can get a copy of it and also post the output of `md5sum Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`. Does it match the md5sum provided on the site you downloaded this from (if any)?

Comment: @terdon I already edited the post with the information I have. I don't know the md5sum from the original site. I will get in touch with the person who gave me this, so that can have some more answers...

Comment: Since it's a binary, I'd suggest to try it on a different architecture, try in a i386 VM if your 12.04 host is amd64.

Comment: @SylvainPineau thanks for your input, but can you be a bit more specific? I don't understant what I must do... How do I try it in a different architecture? And, for that matter, how do I know if my 12.04 host is amd64? Sorry to bother you with these questions, but I am not such an advanced user...

Comment: @EDias first, ask your friend to check the md5sum of their copy. Do they match?

Comment: @terdon Indeed they do not match! My friend's version returned `5c7712ee4eaccd607cea26a326db7c30  Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh`.

Comment: @muru I guess you were right, it must have been corrupted. I tried with a new copy of my friend's version and it worked! Now it's running perfectly! Thank you very much for all your answers, they were a great help! :D

Answer (score 1):

The md5sum for your file (Mathematica_10.0.0_LINUX.sh) should be `5c7712ee4eaccd607cea26a326db7c30` according to http://www.math.uri.edu/~alex/Mathematica/instructions.txt.

They don't provide the same version but you can download [Mathematica_10.1.0_LINUX.sh](http://www.math.uri.edu/~alex/Mathematica/Mathematica_10.1.0_LINUX.sh) from the same site (2015 version).

```
MD5 checksums:

1523e5ed52161e8bb3f55bd688e11f35  Mathematica_10.1.0_LINUX.sh
```

Comment: Well, I tried a different version, which had a different md5sum with respect to my original file, and that's not that one as well. However, that new version worked perfectly (I guess mine must have been corrupted, as someone said in the comments...)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it must have been my file that was corrupted... I had this file from a friend and something must have happened while copying it or something. I asked him for the file again, copied it and, this time, it worked!

Thank you very much @mutu, @terdon and @Sylvain Pineau, you were a great help!